# Trying to insert a table from Excel into Word but getting the error "file is locked for editing.." by myself?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a code that reads a dynamic Excel table into an existing Word document and changes some variables in the document (for example %Username%)

The code below gives me an "Locked for editing" error by myself, but that isn't the case.

Can someone see what I have to change in the code?

The code is:

```
Sub Export_Table_Word()

    'Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdbmRange As Word.Range

    'Excel objects.
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rnReport As Range

    'Path of Word Template
    Dim stPathTemplate As String
    Dim stPathSave As String

    'Dynamic Replace variables
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim StrFind
    Dim StrRepl As String

    'Loop variable
    Dim i As Long

    Dim msWord As Object
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Define replacement variables
    UserName = Application.UserName

     sFirst = Split(UserName, " ")(0) 'Firstname                         'sFirst = Split(UserName, ",")(1) 'Firstname
    sLast = Split(UserName, " ")(1)  'Lastname
    sUserName = Left(sFirst, 1) & sLast  'First letter of firstname and lastname
    sFullName = sFirst & " " & sLast  'Full name

    StrFind = "%User_Name%,%Full_name%, %Date%"   'Strings to be replaced in the word document
    StrRepl = sUserName & "*" & sFullName & "*" & " " & Date    'Replaced by

    'Initialize Path word template
    stPathTemplate = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\VBA_TEST\VBA_Automation.docx"
    stPathSave = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\VBA_TEST\Finished.docx"

    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rnReport = wsSheet.Range("D2:D7")

    'Initialize the Word objets.
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(stPathTemplate)
    Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Report").Range

    'If the macro has been run before, clean up any artifacts before trying to paste the table in again.
    On Error Resume Next
    With wdDoc.InlineShapes(1)
        .Select
        .Delete
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With wdDoc
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open (stPathTemplate)     
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
             .ClearFormatting
             .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, ",")) 'Loop to replace all the defined dynamic strings
             .Text = Split(StrFind, ",")(i)
             .Replacement.Text = Split(StrRepl, "*")(i)
             .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next i

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = 1               'FindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            .Execute Replace:=2    'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)       
        End With
    End With

     'Copy the report to the clipboard.
    rnReport.Copy

    'Select the range defined by the "Report" bookmark and paste in the report from clipboard.     
    With wdbmRange
        .Select
        .Paste    
    End With

    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wdDoc
        '.Save
        .SaveAs2 Filename:=stPathSave, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False

        .Close
    End With

    'Quit Word.
    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out your variables.
    Set wdbmRange = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    'Clear out the clipboard, and turn screen updating back on.
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done") 
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably stopped the code at some point during debugging or due to an error before it got to wdApp.Quit. Check your Windows Task manager for instances of Word still running and end them.

Comment: I have have tried that also a lot of times, but stil getting the same error..

Comment: What line triggers the error message?

Comment: You simply open it twice. Set wDoc = ... and With wDoc ....Documents.Open

Comment: Agree with Asger. See here: `With wdDoc : 
            .Visible = True : 
            .Documents.Open (stPathTemplate)  :
            .Activate`  It makes no sense to do `wdDoc.Documents.Open` to open the same document. That will certainly cause the error. You also should NOT use `.Activate : With ActiveDocument.Content` that immediately follows. If this should be the same document `wdDoc.Content` Would be the right approach. If this is supposed to be a different document (you actually want to open a different one) declare and assign an additional object variable, then use that.

Comment: @CindyMeister Can you help me with the syntax that I have to use? Because when I'm trying to remove the whole with wdDoc ... then the part with : .ActviveDocument Content Find wouldn't work ( even when I try to use your approache with wdDoc.Content. I don't know how to adjust the code so that it will work..

Comment: For this question, delete that second line that tries to open the document again. That should solve *this* question. Then, if the code is still not giving you the end solution start a new question based on that.

Comment: Thank you for that. The "is locked for editing" bug is solved, but now the code gives this error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" error at the line: .activedocument.contentfind ( it also gives the same error when I delete that line).